# Easytimer.js is not loading

Tags: javascript

I want to use the Easytimer.js(https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/) libary but I get the following error in chrome:

> applet.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Timer is not defined
>       at applet.js:1

Here's my code:

```js
var timer = new Timer();
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
  $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/applet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Content -->

  <div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>

  <!-- /Content -->

  <script src="js/easytimer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is already loaded before the script starts?

Comment: I put this code in: `if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
    console.log("loaded");
}` and I got no console output...

Comment: what about `console.log(document.readyState);`?

Comment: Genius ^^ it says loading... :/

Comment: This may have to do with Internet Explorer and it's cache problems, try clearing your cache and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno if you need jQuery, but it should be loaded first, then Easytimer, then last your script.

```js
var timer = new Timer();
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
  $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easytimer@1.1.1/dist/easytimer.min.js"></script>
<div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easytimer@1.1.1/dist/easytimer.min.js"></script>
<div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>
<script>
var timer = new Timer();
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
  $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});
</script>
```

Comment: you helped me, I guess :D

If I use the js in my "js" Folder it does not work, but with the link (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easytimer@1.1.1/dist/easytimer.min.js) it does. Any explanation?

Comment: It is better practice to define the event listener before the event might be triggered. See [my version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541069/295783)

Answer (score 0):

In the document, attach Easytimer and jQuery first (or jQuery and Easytimer - is Easytimer jQuery-dependent?), then your script.

Answer (score 0):

1. move jQuery script tags to the top and use it throughout
2. It is best practice to add the event listener before you trigger start
3. Execute timer when page has loaded

```js
$(function() {
  var timer = new Timer();
  $(timer).on('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
    $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
  });
  timer.start();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easytimer@1.1.1/dist/easytimer.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Content -->

  <div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>

  <!-- /Content -->

</body>

</html>
```

Or without jQuery:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  var timer = new Timer();
  timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('basicUsage').innerHTML =timer.getTimeValues().toString();
  });
  timer.start();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easytimer@1.1.1/dist/easytimer.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Content -->

  <div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>

  <!-- /Content -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

The DOM isn't loaded.

This could be because of the following:

1. There's an error in the cache.
2. The script started too early.

Try clearing the cache of your browser, if that doesnt work, this:

```
 $(window).on('load', function(){ // Your code }
```

or in pure JavaScript:

```
 window.onload = function () {// Your code }
```

Comment: @LukasThiersch try this `if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load); // Document still loading so DomContentLoaded can still fire :)
} else {
    load();
}`

Comment: @Sam Don't post code in comments. Update your answer - except the code in the comment is not very useful